# Anime with teenager fighting huge fish-looking monster that could fly

Tags: story-identification, anime

I don't remember much about it because I was so young at the time. I would say it came out somewhere between 80s to early 90s judging by the art style.

Things that I clearly remember are:

- The main character was a teen boy with brown hair. He might have had a younger little sister there.
- Fighting a huge fish (green or yellow) looking monster that could fly. Imagine a big-ass catfish looking thing.
- Actual fight was some large cliffside surrounded by sea

Can't remember if there were mechas, planes or if he was using a fishing rod.

It's not much to go on but hopefully someone recognizes what I'm referring to.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! These might help you to improve your question; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [How to ask a good (anime) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question/11875#11875)

Comment: @Niffler Please don't make pointless edits.

Answer (score 1):

It is more recent than you're looking for, but the 2011 TV series [Hunter x Hunter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Hunter_%C3%97_Hunter_(2011)_episodes) fits the criteria:

> The story begins with a young boy named Gon.... In order to prove his
>   ability to take the exam, Gon catches the local monster fish, "Lord of
>   the Lake".

The main character, Gon, carries and uses a fishing pole as a tool/weapon (as well as using it to fish with!).  I seem to recall he was on a cliff for part of the fight, perhaps the one along the right in this picture:

[image: Gon fighting monster fish]

The main character looks like this:

[image: Gon using fishing pole]

Comment: Not sure this fits. Besides the time difference, Gon's hair is dark green, not brown, and the Lord of the Lake is blue, not green or yellow.

Comment: @F1Krazy yeah I think it's a long shot, but figured it was worth suggesting, if only for disambiguation.  And people are going to end up here searching for "fishing rod."

Comment: it's not HxH, nothing as well known or popular.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is [*Cencoroll*](https://myanimelist.net/anime/3087/Cencoroll?q=cen).

A [second one](https://myanimelist.net/anime/9488/Cencoroll_2) is planned to be released

Comment: Could you [edit] to explain how this matches the description in the question?

Comment: yeah nope. Like i said it definetly looks like something from 80s-90s